# Converting .bmp to .png using powershell causes memory leak

Tags: powershell, image-processing, memory

**Intro**

I am trying to convert '.bmp' files to '.png' files. I found a piece of code earlier that does this using PowerShell. What happens is with every image converted the increment increased in my RAM usage is roughly equal to the size of an image. This increases to the max RAM I have and slows down my PC.

**Question**

Do I need to release the loaded images from RAM, and if so, how would I do this?

**Code**

The code I am using is from here: https://code.adonline.id.au/change-image-formats-powershell/

[image: Memory usage]

Code used:

```
$usb1 = 'U:'
$usb2 = 'F:'
$usb3 = 'H:'
$usb4 = 'J:'
$usb5 = 'K:'
$usb6 = 'I:'

$usblist = $usb1,$usb2,$usb3,$usb4,$usb5,$usb6

foreach($usbs in  $usblist){
$usb = $usbs
############################# convert ###################################
function ConvertImage{
    param ([string]$path)
        foreach($path in Get-ChildItem -Directory $usb -Recurse){
Write-Host $path
            #Load required assemblies and get object reference  
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
        foreach($file in (ls "$path\*.bmp")){
            $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)
            $newfilname = ($file.Fullname -replace '([^.]).bmp','$1') + ".png"
            $convertfile.Save($newfilname, "png")
            $file.Fullname
    }  
 }
};ConvertImage -path $args[0] 
}
```

PS. I would prefer to keep using PowerShell, as I use this for further processing the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap) is disposable. [Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose#system-drawing-image-dispose) it after use. Also, there is no need to re-define functions or re-load assemblies multiple times.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

$paths = 'U:', 'F:', 'H:', 'J:', 'K:', 'I:'

foreach ($path in $paths) {
    Get-ChildItem -File "$path\*.bmp" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $bitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::new($_.FullName)
        $newname = $_.FullName -replace '.bmp$','.png'
        $bitmap.Save($newname, "png")
        $bitmap.Dispose()
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It doesn't only fix my issue, the conversion is now blazingly fast! 

For my understanding, the main reason it's faster now is because you moved the assembly out of the loop?

Comment: @Olaf Not sure to be honest, I don't have a gut feeling for how long it takes to load an assembly twice because I generally don't do that. ;) There is only one way to find out. Move it back in and see how much of a difference it makes.

Comment: Gradually converting from working code back to code that is broken in some respect is a powerful way to learn. I can only encourage you to revert my changes to your code and see which issues re-appear at which stage.

Comment: As the `Bitmap.Save()` method may throw an exception I suggest to use `try {...} finally {$bitmap.Dispose()}` to make sure there are no memory leaks in case of an error.

Comment: @Olaf Consider zett42's comment. The chances for an error on save are relatively low (practically only "disk full", "access denied", and sudden disconnect of a removable volume), but proper resource handling in case of an error should be part of a production-level script.

Comment: @Tomalak Completely agree. I have done some testing and it appears to not have sped up a lot actually [sorry!]. 

zett42 I ran it on about 5k images without any issues, but will keep this in mind if any errors pop up! thank you!